# Apache POI - Error while merging pptx

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, xslf

I have a scenario where I need to copy few slides from a pptx (source.pptx) and download it as a separate pptx file (output.pptx) based on the presentation notes available in the slides.
I am using apache poi to achieve it. This is my code.

```
String filename = filepath+"\\source.pptx";
    try {
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(filename));
        XMLSlideShow outputppt = new XMLSlideShow();
        XSLFSlide[] slides = ppt.getSlides();

        for (int i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            try {
                XSLFNotes mynotes = slides[i].getNotes();
                for (XSLFShape shape : mynotes) {
                    if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
                        XSLFTextShape txShape = (XSLFTextShape) shape;
                        for (XSLFTextParagraph xslfParagraph : txShape.getTextParagraphs()) {
                            if (xslfParagraph.getText().equals("NOTES1") || xslfParagraph.getText().equals("NOTES2")) {
                                outputppt.createSlide().importContent(slides[i]);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.pptx");
        outputppt.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I open the output.pptx which is created, I am getting the following
error:
"PowerPoint found a problem with the content in output.pptx
PowerPoint can attempt to repair the presentation
If you trust the source of this presentation, click Repair."

Upon clicking repair: "PowerPoint removed unreadable content in merged.pptx
[Repaired].  You should review this presenation to determine whether any content
was unexpectedly changed or removed"
And I can see blank slides with "Click to add Title" and "Click to add Subtitle"

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me to copy slide content, layout and notes.
Just modify the code to your needs if you want to follow your original question. I assume you simple have to:

1. not import the slide content from it's source slide
2. copy the notes content to the slide instead

   ```
       // get the layout from the source slide
       XSLFSlideLayout layout = srcSlide.getSlideLayout();
       XSLFSlide newslide = ppt
           .createSlide(defaultMaster.getLayout(layout.getType()))
           .importContent(srcSlide);
       XSLFNotes srcNotes = srcSlide.getNotes();
       XSLFNotes newNotes = ppt.getNotesSlide(newslide);
       newNotes.importContent(srcNotes);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error in a case where some text boxes were empty. Solved it by always setting an empty text in all placeholders when creating slides.

```
XSLFSlide slide = presentation.createSlide(slideMaster.getLayout(layout));
// remove any placeholder texts
for (XSLFTextShape ph : slide.getPlaceholders()) {
  ph.clearText();
  ph.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Definitely not a generally valid answer.